# WCF Service & Request queueing

Tags: multithreading, wcf, scalability, request-queueing

Is using a handrolled POCO queue class using pseudo code

```
T Dequeue() {
   lock(syncRoot) { 
      if(queue.Empty) Thread.Wait(); 
   }
}

void Enqueue(T item) {
   queue.Enqueue(item);
   Thread.Notify();
}
```

For WCF is request queueing a scalable approach?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

WCF service throttling will queue requests internally without any additional code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Jezell,  Thanks for the reply.  I just joined a new company. All their WCF services are just shims that post incoming requests to respective internal queues.  And then agents are performing what is needed.  I was wondering if this is the best way accomplish this.

Comment: If you want durable queues, netMsmqBinding is the way to go. If you don't need durable queues, WCF channel listeners will queue up incoming requests automatically based on the throttles in the configuration.

Comment: Jezell, can you direct me to a link where I can learn more about this?  This sounds very interesting...

Answer (score 1):

No it is not, because as you add more servers your solution can not scale, and is not reliable.

You should be using the built in [WCF Queue Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx).